# Python dataframe np.select - maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I want to assign a specific value to a dataframe row when values are between two numbers as follow.

I get an error "maximum recursion depth exceeded".

Can you please help me fix it?

```
dfmerged['OptionType'] = np.select(
[
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'C', dfmerged['delta'] >= 0.75),
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'C', dfmerged['delta'] < 0.75 , dfmerged['delta'] > 0.55 ),
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'C', dfmerged['delta'] <= 0.55, dfmerged['delta'] > 0.45),
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'C', dfmerged['delta'] <= 0.45, dfmerged['delta'] >= 0.25),
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'C', dfmerged['delta'] < 0.25),
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'P', dfmerged['delta'] <= -0.75),
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'P', dfmerged['delta'] > -0.75, dfmerged['delta'] < -0.55),
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'P', dfmerged['delta'] >= -0.55, dfmerged['delta'] < -0.45),
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'P', dfmerged['delta'] >= -0.45, dfmerged['delta'] <= -0.25),
    np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'P', dfmerged['delta'] < -0.25),
],
[
    'Deep ITM',
    'ITM',
    'ATM',
    'OTM',
    'Deep OTM',
    'Deep ITM',
    'ITM',
    'ATM',
    'OTM',
    'Deep OTM'
```

**EDIT #1**

I tried the following and get this error : Length of values (1) does not match length of index (8344)... Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

```
right_c = dfmerged['right'] == 'C'
right_p = dfmerged['right'] == 'P'
above_075 = dfmerged['delta'] >= 0.75
tween_055_075 = np.logical_and( dfmerged['delta'] < 0.75, dfmerged['delta'] > 0.55 )
tween_045_055 = np.logical_and( dfmerged['delta'] <= 0.55, dfmerged['delta'] > 0.45 )
tween_025_045 = np.logical_and( dfmerged['delta'] <= 0.45, dfmerged['delta'] >= 0.25 )
below_025 = dfmerged['delta'] < 0.25
p_below_075 = dfmerged['delta'] <= -0.75,
p_tween_075_055 = np.logical_and(dfmerged['delta'] > -0.75, dfmerged['delta'] < -0.55),
p_tween_055_045 = np.logical_and(dfmerged['delta'] >= -0.55, dfmerged['delta'] < -0.45),
p_tween_045_025 = np.logical_and(dfmerged['delta'] >= -0.45, dfmerged['delta'] <= -0.25),
p_below_075_025 = np.logical_and(dfmerged['right'] == 'P', dfmerged['delta'] < -0.25)

dfmerged['OptionType'] = np.select(
     [
        np.logical_and(right_c, above_075),
        np.logical_and(right_c, tween_055_075),
        np.logical_and(right_c, tween_045_055),
        np.logical_and(right_c, tween_025_045),
        np.logical_and(right_c, below_025),
        np.logical_and(right_p, p_below_075),
        np.logical_and(right_p, p_tween_075_055),
        np.logical_and(right_p,p_tween_055_045),
        np.logical_and(right_p,p_tween_045_025),
        np.logical_and(right_p,p_below_075_025)
    ],
      [
          'Deep ITM',
          'ITM',
          'ATM',
          'OTM',
          'Deep OTM',
          'Deep ITM',
          'ITM',
          'ATM',
          'OTM',
          'Deep OTM'
      ],
      default='Unknown')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just brainstorming here, but Python doesn't have a global optimizer, so that's going to parse dfmerged['right'] 10 times and dfmerged['delta'] 16 times.  I suggest you be your own global optimizer:

```
right_c = dfmerged['right'] == 'C'
right_p = dfmerged['right'] == 'P'
above_075 = dfmerged['delta'] >= 0.75
tween_055_075 = np.and( dfmerged['delta'] < 0.75, dfmerged['delta'] > 0.55 )
tween_045_055 = np.and( dfmerged['delta'] <= 0.55, dfmerged['delta'] > 0.45 )
tween_025_045 = np.and( dfmerged['delta'] <= 0.45, dfmerged['delta'] > 0.25 )
below_025 = dfmerged['delta'] < 0.25
dfmerged['OptionType'] = np.select(
[
    np.logical_and[ right_c, above_075 ),
    np.logibal_and[ right_c, tween_055_075 ),
... etc ...
]
```

Although I see now that I have the signs wrong for the 'P' entities, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Any idea how to fix the above?